# Statistical analysis of clustered data- but clusters in one comparison group only

Tags: cluster-sample

I'm curious if it's still valid to use analysis techniques for clustered data when only one of the two comparison groups consists of multiple clusters.

For example, the control group consists of 10 schools, but the intervention group consists of one school only. Analysis is at the individual student level.
Intuitively, I would think that adjusting for clusters should still be done since students from the same school would be more similar to each other than to students from a different school. But, does having only 1 school in the intervention group make a difference?

Comment: Personally, I would want to know each of the 11 schools clusters with respect to all possible binary comparisons between schools. Granted, that makes for 55 comparisons, but I think that only then can one establish how the clustering of the 11th school compares to all other potential clusters.